# extract pattern from file and the file name

Tags: awk

I have the following problem:

I have a large number of files that have the following name:`mfifm-slab-l1=XX-l2=YY-scf.out`. `XX` and `YY` are numbers from 1 to 27. I am able to extract the info that I want from the files and print it along with the file names like so (imagine many different lines like this):

```
.
.
.
mfifm-slab-l1=3-l2=17-scf.out     !    total energy              =   -7460.95083408 Ry
.
.
.
```

My question is: is it possible to extract only the XX and YY part from the file name and have it like so:

```
.
.
.
3    17     !    total energy              =   -7460.95083408 Ry
.
.
.
```

Comment: I'm not an awk-person, and I'm sure someone will know how to do it with awk, but with sed I think it would be something like `sed 's/^mfifm-slab-l1=\([0-2]\?[0-9]\)-l2=\([0-2]\?[0-9]\)-scf.out/\1\t\2/g'` (that's a tab `\t` between the first two numbers`\1` and `\2` in the replacement; easy enough to use spaces instead if that's what you want).

Comment: Sounds like something sed would be best used for to me.

Comment: @frabjous ah so I should extract with awk like I am doing now in a file say `result.dat` and then do the sed you mentioned on that file?

Comment: Could either do that, or you could pipe it to sed: `awk ...<whatever> ... | sed ...` I don't know exactly how you're getting that extraction now.

Comment: @frabjous I do this: `awk '/!/{print FILENAME,"   ",$0}' *.out`. Ideally I would like to end up with a file `results.dat` and XX starts at 1 and YY goes from 1 to 27 then XX moves to 2 and so on. But I could also split the whole thing in 27 files.

Comment: I don't see why `awk '/!/{print FILENAME,"   ",$0}' *.out | sed 's/^mfifm-slab-l1=\([0-2]\?[0-9]\)-l2=\([0-2]\?[0-9]\)-scf.out/\1    \2/g' > results.dat` wouldn't work, but of course without access to your files, I can't test that.

Comment: @lucian regarding `so I should extract with awk ... and then do the sed` - no, you don't need sed when you're using awk so piping awk to sed or vice-versa is [almost?] always wrong but there's nothing in your question that would require awk. If you modify your question to show the original input, i.e. before `I am able to extract the info that I want`, and the final expected output of everything you're trying to do then we can help you.

Comment: Btw, remember to [accept answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to or otherwise follow up on [your questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/224652/lucian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original input files aren't present in your question but from the awk script you provided [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716495/extract-pattern-from-file-and-the-file-name#comment1358127_716495):

```
awk '/!/{print FILENAME,"   ",$0}' *.out
```

that you say is producing the input in your question, I think this is would produce the final expected output in your question directly from the original input files:

```
awk 'FNR==1{split(FILENAME,f,/[-=]/)} /!/{print f[4], f[6],"   ",$0}' *.out
```

Here is that second script written more legibly to make it easier to understand:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 {
        split(FILENAME,f,/[-=]/)
    }
    /!/ {
        print f[4], f[6], "   ", $0
    }
' *.out
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! that is precisely what I was looking for. do you mind explaining the bit with this `FNR==` construction in your answer? What is the `f` after `FILENAME` doing'? I use awk at a very basic level to just filter info from output files. These files are produced by a software called Quantum Espresso and each is rather large. In this case at the end of the run I should have about 400+ of them. From each I am extracting the line starting  with `!` (thankfully there is only one line like this in this particular case). I can extract that line but the rest I had no ideea how! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I rewrote the second script with newlines and indentation to make it clearer. As you can see, `f` is the 2nd argument to `split()` so please just look up your awk man page for what `split()` does and the arguments it takes. To learn AWK (which you really should do if you'll be doing any text processing on a Unix system) get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.